# Bag of words em Python

Tags: python, data, pandas, classificação

Tenho um dataset de notícias e quero separá-las entre duas classes. Para isso pensei em usar Bag of words, porém não estou conseguindo com o Sklearn. Tentei o seguinte:

```
#Bag of words
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
print(vectorizer.fit_transform(traindata).todense())
print(vectorizer.vocabulary_)
```

Alguma indicação de como usar Bag of words usando Pandas, Sklearn etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente utilizar a lib [Gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/corpora/dictionary.html) para fazer o preprocessamento dos teus dados. Ela ajuda a produzir a vetorização que você precisa na entrada dos modelos dos modelos do SKLearn.

Experimente algo assim:

```py
from gensim.parsing.preprocessing import preprocess_string, DEFAULT_FILTERS, stem_text
from gensim.corpora import Dictionary

documents = json.load(open('./data/jsons/unprocessed_documents.json'))

def concat_document(doc):
    return 5 * doc['title'] + " " + 3 * " ".join([*doc['topics']]) + " " + doc['abstract']

CUSTOM_FILTERS = set(DEFAULT_FILTERS) - set([stem_text])

preprocessed_texts = []

for base_doc in documents:
    concat_doc = concat_document(base_doc)
    preprocessed_texts.append(preprocess_string(concat_doc, CUSTOM_FILTERS))


dic = Dictionary(preprocessed_texts)

corpus_bow = [dic.doc2bow(doc) for doc in preprocessed_texts]

print(corpus_bow[0])

> [(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 1), (4, 3), (5, 19), (6, 4), (7, 2), (8, 1), (9, 5), (10, 6), (11, 2), (12, 9), (13, 6), (14, 1), (15, 5), (16, 3), (17, 1), (18, 1), (19, 16), (20, 2), (21, 1), (22, 1), (23, 1), (24, 3), (25, 18), (26, 1), (27, 3), (28, 1), (29, 1), (30, 3), (31, 1), (32, 3), (33, 1), (34, 8), (35, 24), (36, 3), (37, 6), (38, 3), (39, 1), (40, 1), (41, 1), (42, 2), (43, 3), (44, 5), (45, 4), (46, 1), (47, 2), (48, 5), (49, 6), (50, 9), (51, 6), (52, 1), (53, 15), (54, 31), (55, 6), (56, 5), (57, 15), (58, 1), (59, 1), (60, 2), (61, 14), (62, 1), (63, 1), (64, 5), (65, 6), (66, 1), (67, 2), (68, 1), (69, 6), (70, 3), (71, 15), (72, 1)]
```

Com o BoW pronto, você só precisa agora colocar ele no formato que o seu modelo aceita, um array numpy esparço, por exemplo.

Comment: Entendido, Tomás. A pergunta em si era bem abrangente `Alguma indicação de como usar Bag of words usando Pandas, Sklearn etc?`. =[
Vou tentar melhorar minha resposta.